# Good reason not to do this: Pub/Sub with only 1 topic and publishers are also subscribers

Tags: architecture, event-programming, azure, pubsub, service-bus

Looking for a good reason to avoid this solution.

## Problem

- Multiple microservices/SAAS, each storing the same data that needs to be synced (example is customer contact details).

  - 1st is an OAuth microservice.
  - 2nd is a CRM that supports Pub/Sub pattern.
  - 3rd new microservice
  - possibly a 4th like marketing automation (Hubspot, Marketo, Braze)
- When updating the contact details in any of the microservices/SAAS, the others need to sync as well.
- Staff is currently banging their heads, updating multiple locations everytime a customer needs to update their data. Which is about 200+ per month.

## Solution

- Event driven Publish/Subscribe pattern using Azure Service Bus with only 1 topic, and all publishers are subscribers as well because the update can come from any source.
- **Sample scenario:** Microservice-A would make a local update then publish a message. B and C would receive the message and update on their end.

  - B can publish as well, so A and C can update themselves.
  - and so on.

**Consideration: Idempotency**

- Publisher can receive its own message, since this publisher will be one of the subscribers as well.
- I'm currently researching a way for the publisher to exclude itself from the receivers, using some kind of routing filter.
- Message handling must be idempotent for concurrent updates from multiple sources. Last one wins.

**Consideration: Out of sync**

- I need a way to know whos out-of-sync. Possibly an instrumentation from the infrastructure layer hooked in, or an extra all-knowing microservice that tracks changes and queries for inconsistencies. I don't know yet.

**Consideration: Infinite loops**

- Some kind of mechanism to avoid subscribers republishing the same message. There has to be clear separation from code level.
- To catch infinite loops from infrastructure layer, maybe a notification if the same message has been queued for X times.

Comment: Understandable for services #2 and #4, but is there any reason for #1 and #3 to update contact details of their own volition? Limiting the number of places where it happens will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @guillaume31 #1 act as a membership provider, customers can edit their own mobile-number, self-service from a customer portal. #2 will eventually become the centralized agent portal, where they can view and edit customer information (this is very far from the future, and we need something to support current operations).

Comment: What approach do you intend to take in case of concurrent changes? Last one wins?

Comment: @guillaume31 yes, last one wins.

Comment: Sorry, I mean #3

Comment: Isn't this as simple as including a source identifier in the message? Rather than messing with routing the sender could detect a message to be its own and ignore it.

Comment: @MartinMaat - Thanks for the input. Will consider this as well. The challenge I see is the extra coding on our CRM and other Saas.